# Suggest a tool to Automate Test the Live Video Call or chat feature which could help in checking the Quality

Tags: automated-testing, quality-assurance

I am looking for a tool which could test my app which is for Video and Voice calling and check its Quality too.

We want to Automate our app of Video and Voice calls on Web, IOS and Android (mobile & tabs) and We want to check the Quality of the Calls too.

Comment: What do you mean by the "quality of the calls"? Which parameters are interesting in your context? Additionally, what do you mean by "automate our app"? Which risks are you trying to investigate?

Comment: Thanks for response. I want to test an application which can be available on Web, Mobile (iOS Android), or a Desktop application. This app has feature of calling (Voice and Video). I want to Automate this feature and further i want to test the Quality of Video and Voice. Does this Answer your Question? So our scope is to Automate the calling feature for 2 or more callers and check the Quality or issues in Video and Voice.

Comment: @AmitVerma: "I want to test the Quality of Video and Voice" but how do you ecognise that? Surely you want to look at some parameters that tell you more about the video calls. What parameters do you have in mind?

Comment: Pixels, BitRate, Network Quality,